# Joe Mama or Joe Biden

Tags: code-golf, string, random

## Your task

Randomly pick and print "Joe Mama" or "Joe Biden" in as little bytes as possible.

### Rules

- No trailing lines, spaces, or anything else weird like that
- No election fraud! Both "Joe Mama" and "Joe Biden" must have equal chaces of winning

### Prize

The winner will get a spot in https://github.com/Sid220/joe-mama-or-joe-biden, even if that language is already there.

### Example (not code golfed)

```js
var joe = Math.random() < 0.5;

if (joe <= 0.5){
  joe = true;
} else{
  joe = false;
}

if (joe == true) {
console.log('Joe Mama');
} else {
  console.log('Joe Biden');
}
```

Comment: Any reason why trailing newlines aren't allowed?

Answer (score 5):

## HTML/Javascript <s>61</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 49 bytes

```html
<script>alert('Joe '+(new Date%2?"Mama":"Biden"))
```

-9 thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94066/makonede) (and me being dumb)
-2 thanks to [Unmitigated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99986/unmitigated)

### HTML/Javascript, 60 bytes

```html
<script>alert('Joe '+(new Date()%2?"Mama":"Biden"))</script>
```

-1 thanks to Redwolf Programs

### HTML/Javascript, 61 bytes

```html
<script>alert('Joe '+["Mama","Biden"][new Date()%2])</script>
```

Haven't ever submitted anything before so not sure if I did it right

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I think you might be able to save a byte using ternary instead of an array.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! You don't need the <script> tags BTW if you change the language to Javascript

Comment: @wasif They're answering in HTML+JS, not pure JS

Comment: `new Date()%2` can be reduced to `new Date%2`.

Comment: The closing `</script>` is unnecessary.

Comment: I assumed so as well but it doesn't seem like it is; the stack snippet doesn't seem to work without it

Comment: @Komali the stack snippet working doesn't matter, if it works after pasting into a local HTML file and opening it then it counts

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <sup><s>18</s></sup> <sup><s>17</s></sup> 16 bytes

```
‛ɾ∷«W≤ḂΠǔ«½ǐ℅"Ṅ₴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJvJvuKIt8KrV+KJpOG4gs6gx5TCq8K9x5DihIVcIuG5hOKCtCIsIiIsIiJd)

Explanation:

```
‛ɾ∷               # "Joe"
   «W≤ḂΠǔ«        # "bidenmama"
          ½       # Split in half
           ǐ      # Title Case
            ℅     # Random choice
             "    # Wrap with "Joe"
              Ṅ   # Join by space
               ₴  # Print without newline
```

If trailing newlines were allowed, this could be <sup><s>14</s></sup> 13 bytes: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaEiLCIiLCLigJvJvuKIt8KrV+KJpOG4gs6gx5TCq8K9x5DihIUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good thought, but that comes out to 18 bytes as well: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJvJvuKIt8Kr4oaU4oi1yoDigbrPhMabYcKrx5A24bqH4oSFK+KCtCIsIiIsIiJd) I've actually found about 5 different ways of doing it that come out to 18 bytes, but I have an idea that might shave off 1 or 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 27 bytes

```php
Joe <?=time()%2?Biden:Mama;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fKz9VwcbetiQzN1VDU9XI3ikzJTXPyjcxN9H6/38A)

Not that bad for good ole PHP

NOTE: I kinda disapprove political tones in code golf. If you use my answer in the Git, please do not cite my name

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'›¸.•GŠ‰[öÂ•#Ωðý™?
```

Could be 1 byte less if trailing newlines are allowed by removing the trailing `?`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f/VHDrkM7Dm/Qe9SwyP3ogkcNG6IPbzvcBOQpn1vp9ahlkf3//wA)

**Explanation:**

```python
'›¸                '# Push dictionary string "joe"
   .•GŠ‰[öÂ•        # Push compressed string "biden mama"
                    # Split it on spaces: ["biden","mama"]
             Ω      # Pop and push a random item from this pair
              ðý    # Join the stack with newline delimiter
                ™   # Titlecase each word
                 ?  # Print it without trailing newline
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `'›¸` is `"joe"` and `.•GŠ‰[öÂ•` is `"biden mama"`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 29 bytes

```
x"amaM eoJ"H>
>"nediB eoJ"H
V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/v0IpMTfRVyE130vJw47LTikvNSXTCcLlCvv/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ùJoe ûma∞╕╘Ç'n+αwδ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7lKb2Ugw7ttYeKInuKVleKVmMOHJ24rzrF3zrT//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
ùJoe               # Push string "Joe"
                   # Push a space character " "
     ûma           # Push string "ma"
        ∞          # Double it to "mama"
         ╕╘Ç       # Push compressed string "bide"
            'n+   '# "Append an "n": "biden"
               α   # Pair the top two values: ["mama","biden"]
                w  # Pop and push a random item
                 δ # Titlecase it
                   # (after which the entire stack joined together is output
                   # implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Joe ‽⪪BidenMama⁵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJKz9VQUnTmgvCDUrMS8nP1QguyMkEyjllpqTm@SbmJirpKJhqampa////X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Joe                 Literal string `Joe `
                    Implicitly print
      BidenMama     Literal string `BidenMama`
     ⪪         ⁵    Split into substrings of length 5
    ‽               Random choice of substring
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22 bytes

```
Biden
?)`
Mama
^
Joe
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8spMyU1j8teM4HLNzE3kSuOyys/VeH/fwA) Explanation:

```
Biden
```

Replace the empty input with `Biden`.

```
Mama
```

Replace the empty input with `Mama`.

```
?)`
```

Random choice of one of the two replacements.

```
^
Joe
```

Prefix `Joe`  to the above.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 76 bytes

```
@set/ar=%random%%%2
@if %r%==1 (set/p=Joe Biden<nul)else set/p=Joe Mama<nul
```

Alternative approach, also 76 bytes:

```
@set/ar=%random%%%2
@set s=Mama
@if %r%==1 set s=Biden
@set/p=Joe %s%<nul
```

Explanation:

```
@set/ar=%random%%%2
```

Set `r` equal to either `0` or `1` with equal probability.

```
@set s=Mama
```

Set `s` equal to `Mama`.

```
@if %r%==1 set s=Biden
```

But if `r` is `1`, then change `s` to `Biden`.

```
@set/p=Joe %s%<nul
```

Output `s` prefixed by `Joe` and without a trailing newline.

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes

```python
import time
print"Joe "+["Mama","Biden"][time.time()%2<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EySs/VUFJO1rJNzE3UUlHySkzJTVPKTYapEIPRGhoqhrZGMb@/w8A)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
import time
print("Joe "+["Mama","Biden"][time.time()%2<1],end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EQ8krP1VBSTtayTcxN1FJR8kpMyU1Tyk2GqRED0RoaKoa2RjG6qTmpdiqq2v@/w8A)

Assuming no new trailing whitespace allowed

Answer (score -1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
from random import*
print"Joe "+["Mama","Biden"][randint(0,1)],
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVKHnlpyooaUcr@SbmJirpKDllpqTmKcVGg9QCpTUMdAw1Y3X@/wcA)

Comment: remove the parentheses lol

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Sometimes I miss to do the obvious things.

Comment: The challenge states to output without trailing newline.

Comment: Also this does not have equal chance because %7 can output 7 different values

Comment: @wasif is this fixed now?

Comment: Using the memory locations of things as if they're random isn't allowed IIRC

Comment: @AlanBagel yes now fixed

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms now fixed

Comment: @AlanBagel the newest edit makes it a duplicate of my answer

Comment: @wasif it cannot have a trailing newline. i will edit mine to use random.

Answer (score -1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 46 bytes

```javascript
print(Math.random()<.5?"Joe Mama":"Joe Biden")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EwzexJEOvKDEvJT9XQ9NGz9ReySs/VcE3MTdRyQrMdMpMSc1T0vz/HwA)

Good catch of AlanBagel and 2 byte save by arnauld

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 54 bytes

```javascript
console.log("Joe "+(Math.random()<0.5?"Mama":"Biden"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dQ8krP1VBSVvDN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dD08ZAz9ReyTcxN1HJSskpMyU1T0lT8/9/AA)

Comment: Why not use alert?

Comment: Actually, since this is V8, you can use `print`. Also: `0.5` --> `.5`.

Comment: @AlanBagel good catch !!

Comment: @Arnuald nice thanks!

Comment: BTW, it's shorter without factoring: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EwzexJEOvKDEvJT9XQ9NGz9ReySs/VcE3MTdRyQrMdMpMSc1T0vz/HwA)

Comment: As pointed out by https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107433/leo-but-not-the-other-guy in an attempted suggested edit, you can do `print("Joe", ...)` to save the bytes from factoring again.